# How to change font size in eclipse H_e_l_p browser on Linux

Tags: eclipse, font-size

I'm trying to change the font size on the eclipse (Mars CDT) help browser (not workspace). The intro page has font size buttons, but they only apply to the opening page, not to the help browser.

Comment: Hmm, can you say how you get to this help browser? If I understand your question correctly ctrl + mouse scroll works as is ctrl + "+".

Comment: I'm on linux. Any help page you open (say, through the help menu) opens on a special help browser. CTRL+ does nothing, and I can't find where to define it for the help browser.

Comment: Are you doing in Eclipse: `Help` - > `Help contents` or something else. Please try to be more specific, so that i can try helping